# Showing that every convergent sequence in $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is eventually constant

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

I'm trying to show that every convergent sequence in $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is eventually constant. My professor told me to prove and use the following fact:

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and let $(a_n)_n\subseteq X$ be an injective convergent sequence. Then, there exists a subsequence $(b_n)_n$ of $(a_n)_n$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an open neighborhood $V_n$ of $b_n$ such that the $V_n$s are pairwise disjoint.

I've already proved this fact, but I don't know how to use it to solve the initial problem. I've attempted to show it by contradiction, assuming that there exists a convergent sequence in $\beta\mathbb{N}$ that isn't eventually constant, but I can't seem to find an injective subsequence to use the fact my professor suggested.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Here, $\beta\mathbb{N}$ denotes the Stone-Čech compactification of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Ok.  That explains my puzzlement.  I know nothing about Stone-Čech compactification beyond the fact of its existence.

Comment: This was answered (using the hint you've been given) on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138161/non-trivial-convergent-sequence-in-stone-%C4%8Cech-compactification-of-mathbbn (look at the first answer)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I have a question about that answer: By sequence of distinct ultrafilters does he mean injective sequence of ultrafilters or non eventually constant sequence? If he does not mean the latter, then his argument proves that all convergent sequences are not injective, but that doesn't prove that all convergent sequences are eventually constant.

Comment: @closedrhombus if a sequence only takes finitely many values, then it is clear that it is convergence iff eventually constant (since the space is Hausdorff). Otherwise you can extract an infinite injective subsequence and run the argument from the answer to show that this subsequence isn't convergent, so the original sequence isn't either

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Ok. Now it's way more clear. Thanks a lot for your help.